# Writing to slice of Pandas multindex dataframe is slow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large for loop calculating many variables that ultimately I would like to store in a a Pandas multiindex dataframe. Each step of the loop, I need to write to a slice of the dataframe. The datafram has two row indices and many columns. Each operation needs to write to a slice defined as: all top index, one particular second index, and one particular column. An example of the operation is below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
n_paths = 1000
pathgrid=np.arange(1, n_paths + 1)
dt = 0.25
T = 40
timegrid = np.arange(0, T + dt, dt)
multiindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pathgrid, timegrid], names=['Path', 'Timestep'])
df=pd.DataFrame(index=multiindex,columns=['Values'])

input = np.random.random_sample(n_paths)
i=0
%timeit df.loc[(pathgrid,i),'Values'] = input

868 ms ± 8.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I'm finding this very slow, which make my total runtime very slow as the operation needs to be performed hundreds of times. Is there a faster way to do this using Pandas? The only alternative I am aware of is storing the values in a separate Numpy array, and writing the Numpy array to the dataframe after the loop. But this means I have to create a large number of these temporary arrays

Comment: I think the above is not the original code, so cannot give recommendation. For example I am not sure if the dataframe is written to a file. However, you mentioned that "the datafram has two row indices and many columns", then we should expect it would take more memory and times to operate.  Suggest you to test your code on s computer with more memory.

Comment: It's not a memory issue, I have plenty of free memory for this operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.loc[(pathgrid,i),'Values'] = input
```

performs assignment of respective value from `input` to row where `Timestep==0.0` in `len(input)`-passes. Hence it is slow.

I propose to assign the value in one pass using a function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def assignValue(df, timestep, values):
    for path, new_df in df.groupby(level=0):
        new_df.loc[(path, timestep)] = values[path-1]


n_paths = 1000
pathgrid=np.arange(1, n_paths + 1)
dt = 0.25
T = 40

timegrid = np.arange(0, T + dt, dt)

multiindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [pathgrid, timegrid], names=['Path', 'Timestep'])

df = pd.DataFrame(index=multiindex, columns=['Values'])

input = np.random.random_sample(n_paths)

i = 0
%timeit assignValue(df, 0.0, input)
```

From my computer, the new code takes 315 ms but the original code takes 1.49 s.

**Update**:

The original code does not update the original dataframe object. I use a for-loop and `.loc` to modify the rows and it is faster.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


n_paths = 1000
dt = 0.25
T = 40

pathgrid=np.arange(1, n_paths + 1)
timegrid = np.arange(0, T + dt, dt)

multiindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [pathgrid, timegrid],
    names=['Path', 'Timestep']
)

df = pd.DataFrame(index=multiindex, columns=['Values'])

inputs = np.random.random_sample(n_paths)
%timeit for i in range(1, n_paths+1): df.loc[(i, 0.0)] = inputs[i-1]
```

The new code now takes 80.1 ms.

Comment: This is a nice solution but the runtime is still two slow for my needs. I will resort to using temprorary variables and build the dataframe after my for loop

Comment: See the changes in the original post.

Comment: Wow much faster, impressive. this might work

Comment: What if I want to load a 2d arrary into this multindex dataframe as a new column? Suppose my data is input = np.random.rand(len(pathgrid),len(timegrid)) and I want to load it in like df.loc[(pathgrid,timegrid),'Values'] = input ?  This doesn't work for me though

Wait I think just doing df['Values'] = input.ravel() works and is very fast!

Comment: Really? Assign using for-loop is faster than assign by block? Does that mean pandas did something stupied?